# O que é o ASP.NET vNext? Qual é o nome correto?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, convenções-de-nome

Ok, eu sei que o ASP.NET vNext é a nova versão do ASP.NET sendo lançada pela Microsoft em 2015 e que traz grandes mudanças mudando a forma de trabalhar várias coisas. Este nome vNext era usado como nome de trabalho.

Inicialmente tive a ideia que isto seria o ASP.NET baseado em WebForms na sua versão 5 já que a a última era a 4. E o ASP.NET MVC seria 6 já que a última versão era a 5. De fato a versão dele parece ser 6.0.0.

Mas tenho visto informações dissonantes. Vejo o termo ASP.NET 5 sendo usado para o MVC. E já li que o ASP.NET antigo está praticamente abandonado e na verdade se chamaria ASP.NET 4.6 se ajustando ao nome do .Net como um todo.

Isto significaria que o termo MVC estaria sendo deixado de lado já que ele passaria ser o principal *framework web* suportado pela Microsoft? E de fato apesar do MVC ser versão 6, ele é o que está se chamando de ASP.NET 5?

Qual é a nomenclatura correta de cada um destes dois *frameworks web* na nova versão? Há uma referência canônica e autoritativa que demonstre isto com clareza e confiabilidade? <sup>(para deixar claro que não quero opiniões)</sup>

WebAPI agora está junto com o ASP.NET MVC. Isto significa que este termo desparece, ou seja, não existirá um WebAPI 3?

Muda algo mais sobre isto?

Isto é importante não só para eu saber mas também para usarmos a *tag* correta aqui no site.

Hoje nada disso importa mais, ainda que a pergunta ainda é relevante para entender como o nome foi concebido. [O nome ASP.NET 5 passa ser usado para a nova versão, que é o Core, mas perde essa nomenclatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

Comment: É MS sendo a MS, faz um produto de engenharia complexo e não consegue dar um nome claro para as coisas. Você sabe que o Windows 7 não é versão 7.x, né?

Comment: Realmente isso é um termo muito confuso. Eu sei que o ASP.Net 5 inclui o MVC 6 e o Web API em um único quadro de programação. Porém há fontes contraditórias.

Comment: No próprio site da microsoft informa que para ter referência sobre o ASP.Net 5 deve acessar o site http://www.asp.net/vnext, o que indica, pelo link, que o **vNext** seria o ASP.Net 5.

Comment: Mas esse nome vNext vai desaparecer. Eu estou entendendo que o ASP.Net MVC 6 na verdade vai se chamar ASP.Net 5 e o ASP.Net "clássico" que seria o 5 na verdade vai se chamar ASP.Net 4.6, conforme falei na pergunta. Mas este é o meu entendimento, não sei se está certo.

Comment: As informações mais concretas que encontrei foi neste link http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext que mostra uma série de artigos sobre o ASP.Net 5, e claro o Connect() da MS e o Channel9, que explica um pouco mais.

Comment: Eu também entendi isso, mas creio que o termo vNext irá se "popularizar" e isso dificultará utilizar outros termos, até porque no Channel9 eles utilizam este termo até hoje.

Comment: "ASP.NET 5 is a significant redesign of ASP.NET. This topic introduces the new concepts in ASP.NET 5 and explains how they help you develop modern web apps." Ele não fala que é um redesenho do MVC. Mas todo entendimento é que é isto. Mas e o ASP.Net clássico, como fica?

Comment: A meu ver, aparentemente estão "forçando" a utilização do mesmo.
Uma prova disso foi deixar o projeto Open-Source, levando pessoas a terem mais interesse em analisar e contribuir.

Comment: Encontrei um artigo no **DevMedia** que fala: **"Um dos primeiros aspectos a ser destacado foi a definição de um modelo de programação unificado para a construção de Web sites e serviços. Foram colocados lado a lado mecanismos como ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Web Forms e Web API, com este agrupamento de tecnologias sendo chamado de “MVC 6”."**
Artigo completo: http://www.devmedia.com.br/novidades-do-asp-net-vnext-e-do-visual-studio/31166#ixzz3SrNs1wkL

Comment: Artigos da DevMedia costumam ter muitas informações erradas.

Comment: Sim, mas no final algumas referências no site da microsoft, que ajudam a chegar a sua própria conclusão. Mas também não possui uma definição concreta.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> O que é o ASP.Net vNext?

Uma parte você mesmo respondeu. Seria o nome inicial de trabalho do novo modelo arquitetural do ASP.NET, mas foi um apelido que durou pouco tempo. [Scott Hanselman, um dos responsáveis pelo projeto, declarou os nomes ASP.NET vNext e ASP.NET 5 mortos aqui](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx). O nome correto para o conjunto de arquitetura, ferramentas e metodologia é **ASP.NET Core**, iniciando na versão 1.0.

> Mas tenho visto informações dissonantes. Vejo o termo ASP.Net 5 sendo usado para o MVC. E já li que o ASP.Net antigo está praticamente abandonado e na verdade se chamaria ASP.Net 4.6 se ajustando ao nome do .Net como um todo. Isto significaria que o termo MVC estaria sendo deixado de lado já que ele passaria ser o principal *framework web* suportado pela Microsoft?

Mais ou menos. O suporte continua, mas de uma maneira desencorajada, de forma a atender sistemas legados, como é de praxe de fornecedores de tecnologia. A ideia é que o termo MVC e outros, como o Web API, estejam implícitos no padrão de projetos do ASP.NET Core. A Microsoft unificou as funcionalidades para simplificar o padrão de projetos e manter a arquitetura mais sucinta.

> E de fato apesar do MVC ser versão 6, ele é o que está se chamando de ASP.Net 5?

São duas coisas diferentes. O padrão da arquitetura MVC estaria de fato indo para a sua 6a encarnação. O padrão do ASP.NET estaria indo para a versão 5 tomando como padrão esta versão 6 do MVC como padrão arquitetural de projetos, mais a unificação do Web API, Framework REST feito para o ASP.NET.

Pelo link que citei, Hanselman argumenta que manter um nome como "ASP.NET 5" daria a sensação de eclipsar o ".NET Framework 4.6" em atualização e importância, além de sugerir que seria uma continuação natural do produto (o que não é verdade) então a solução encontrada foi normatizar as nomenclaturas todas para "Core" iniciando na versão 1.0, e com isso, a especificação de um "MVC 6" seguiu o mesmo caminho, fazendo parte da arquitetura ASP.NET Core 1.0.

> Qual é a nomenclatura correta de cada um destes dois *frameworks* web na nova versão? Há uma referência canônica e autoritativa que demonstre isto com clareza e confiabilidade?

Saiu apenas recentemente essa referência. [É este post aqui](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/02/01/an-update-on-asp-net-core-and-net-core/), em que é explicado que algumas nomenclaturas deixarão de ser usadas e que o ASP.NET Core 1.0 precisa ser visto como um outro produto, e não exatamente como uma continuação do ASP.NET 4.6, como antes era esperado que fosse.

> WebAPI agora está junto com o ASP.Net MVC. Isto significa que este termo desparece, ou seja, não existirá um WebAPI 3?

<strike>Não exatamente. O Web API agora é parte do ASP.NET 5. Se ele vai ter um controle próprio é algo que até a data desta resposta ainda não temos.</strike>

O termo desaparece, mas o conceito Web API é mantido como solução REST API do ASP.NET Core 1.0.

> Muda algo mais sobre isto?

Injeções de dependência passam a ser parte do padrão de design do ASP.NET Core 1.0. Também foi incorporado ao modelo arquitetural [o conceito de *Middlewares*](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html), já existentes em outros *frameworks* de outras linguagens, e [o conceito de *Request Features*](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/request-features.html), que trabalha em conjunto com as injeções de dependências e que, aliás, colocamos [em um *framework* que orgulhosamente contribuo](https://github.com/bucknellu/Nyan) um pouco antes.

Comment: Não sei se vai ficar defasado não. Teria que dar uma reviravolta e mudar tudo. Ainda falta uma referência mais clara, não por culpa sua, e acho que é a única coisa que pode ter a necessidade de ser melhorada quando puder. A resposta é boa e acho que ajuda quem está confuso, como eu. Certamente cumpriu o objetivo de dar respostas sem opinião. Este documento do Guthrie foi o que me deixou confuso porque antes parecia ser outra coisa, mas é claro que o que ele fez foi deixar um pouco mais claro o que não estava.

Comment: Na verdade essa imprecisão organizacional faz parte da própria reorganização dessa parte da Microsoft. Como foram um conjunto de coisas alteradas em muito pouco tempo (para o tamanho da empresa e dos times), as equipes ainda não tiveram disponibilidade de documentar tudo. Assim que sair as referências corretas com certeza estarei revisando a resposta.

Comment: Provavelmente, no momento certo, farei a pergunta no meta sobre o uso da *tag*, mas se tiver algum sugestão... Eu acho que os ASP.Net "clássico" continua com a [tag:asp.net], o MVC "antigo" continua com suas *tags* simples ou com o número da versão e este novo MVC deveria usar [tag:asp.net-5]. Pelo menos acho que seria minha ideia inicial.

Comment: @bigown Concordo com sua sugestão.

Comment: Acha que já pode atualizar com o Core para eu aceitar?

Comment: É mesmo. Vamos lá.

Comment: Acho que agora tem tudo. Mudou bastante essa resposta.

Answer (score 6):

**O que é ASP.NET vNext?**

Nada mais é que codenome da proxima versão do Asp.net em desenvolvimento. Digamos, se hoje estamos com a versão Aspnet 5 em produção, a vNext poderá ser Asp.net 6. vide [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_vNext).

Veja esta citação de um artigo de [Carolyn Van SLyck](https://www.linkedin.com/in/vanslyck) (tradução livre):

> vNext é termo da Microsoft para a próxima versão do .NET que é baseado em seu novo compilador OSS (Roslyn). Ele inclui tanto bom e velho .NET e ASP.NET. O objetivo é tornar o desenvolvimento .NET mais fácil, verdadeiramente multiplataforma e cloud amigável. Fonte: [link](http://carolynvanslyck.com/blog/2014/09/dotnet-vnext-impressions/)

O que de fato foi deixado de lado no **Aspnet vNext** é o webform application plattaform, visto que este tipo de aplicação tende ser mais lento e a tarefas de testes ficam desnecessariamente difíceis de serem feitas.

Um ponto importante é que o compilador que vêem sendo desenvolvido no vNext cujo  codinome [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn), sendo que este compilador não dá suporte para webform, contudo, será possível usar a webforms nas próximas versões do AspNet, desde que na hora de compilar, o desenvolvedor troque complidador "Roslyn" para o [CODEDOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6(v=vs.110).aspx) atual compilador em produção. Vide artigo de [Jonathan Allen](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/05/WebForms-VS2013R2).

Comment: Apesar da resposta não fornecer algo conclusivo acho que forneceu informações relevantes para elucidar a questão.

Comment: @bigown eu ainda deixei como wiki para justamente deixar claro que é uma resposta merece ser aprimorada sob diversos pontos de visitas.. eu tive este seu questionamento quanto ao termo Asp.Net vNext e cheguei a achar que se tratava de um novo, mas na verdade é apenas um codinome da plataforma futura em desenvolvimento..

Comment: o vNext em si eu entendo.