# IIS Express ou Owin self host (como serviço)

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, owin, iis

Quais as vantagens/desvantagens destas duas abordagens.

Algumas características:

- Será um servidor `REST`.
- O projeto a principio terá poucas requisições
- Servidor local (não nuvem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É sempre difícil dizer algo sobre esse tipo de situação porque cada caso é um caso e só sabendo **todos** detalhes é que dá para tomar uma decisão razoável. E é complicado porque em geral nem quem está fazendo o projeto sabe de todos os detalhes.

O *self-host* é interessante em casos que você descreveu. Você perde algumas coisas por não usar o IIS, mas fica mais leve e mais simples de administrar. E o que perde provavelmente não será necessário neste cenário mais controlado.

Por tudo o que foi descrito e pelo que já vi da sua intenção eu pensaria em ir de [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) usando OWIN. Dependendo do ciclo do projeto eu já tentaria usar o [ASP.NET vNext](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52158/101) (que depois passou ser chamado de ASP.NET Core, e [perdeu o Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101) no nome) que é a nova versão do Web API. Ele ainda não está pronto mas está bem adiantado.

Se um dia precisa mudar para IIS, é bem simples. Pelo menos do ponto de vista de programação deve ser quase transparente.

O IIS Express não foi feito para uso em produção, portanto, ele até pode ser usado, mas é um motivo a menos para usá-lo.

É claro que você terá que aprender todo o funcionamento do OWIN/Katana. Acho que vale no longo prazo saber isto, mas se tem pressa é melhor usar o que já conhece e não precisa criar códigos específicos. Aí, neste caso, eu iria de IIS normal.