# É correto o termo ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc, terminologia

É correto utilizarmos o termo ASP.NET MVC? Parece que são duas coisas diferentes, tipo, no MVC não utilizamos mais componentes do ASP.NET, utilizamos ou HTML ou Razor ou ambos? Sei que além do Razor também podemos usar o `aspx`, mas o termo ASP.NET MVC parece estar fora do contexto ou não? Ou é correto mesmo o termo?

Comment: Pô! eu postei no SOpt, não entendi porque foi parar no SOen, ixi!!

Comment: A pergunta não estava no SOen, ela estava no meta

Comment: Mas esse tipo de pergunta não deve estar no meta? Achei que seria para o meta, pela questão da tag "debate". Eu postei lá achando ser o local correto. Obrigado pela correção.

Comment: Quanto a sua pergunta, ASP.Net MVC está fora de qual contexto?

Comment: @pnet O meta é direccionado apenas para perguntas relacionadas com o site (http://pt.stackoverflow.com) em si. Podes ler mais sobre o conceito do meta em: [O que é o "meta"? Como ele funciona?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: Por que estão votando para fechar? A pergunta é perfeitamente aceitável (senão eu nem teria migrado do meta pra cá).

Comment: É o espírito do downvote. Sabe como é, @bfavaretto, há aqueles que gostam somente de negativar, sem sequer dar uma contribuição ao site. Por isso eu votei para fechar, pois como havia resposta, pedi para fazer isso, ou seja, remover pois não entendi o downvote recebido, pois não vi nada na pergunta que merecesse isso.

Comment: Certo, mas não confunda downvotes com voto de fechamento. Os downvotes são mais subjetivos, as pessoas votam porque não acharam a pergunta boa, muitas vezes por critérios só delas. Já os votos de fechamento precisam seguir as regras do site, e são mais objetivos, mesmo havendo bastante flexibilidade nas regras.

Comment: Sim, mas o usuário que fez a pergunta ele mesmo está no direito de fechar o post, por diversas razões, certo? Eu poderia ter postado uma informação não pública, por exemplo e pedir para fechar, poderia não concordar com o andamento em que o post está indo e pedir para fechar. Poderia achar que o post está fugindo do objetivo e fechar, enfim, são muitas as razões, certo? Mas ok, vou retirar a minha solicitação, mas entendo perfeitamente tudo isso.

Comment: Na verdade não, como aqui não é um fórum, nada disto é um motivo para fechar a pergunta. Quando a pergunta é feita, e principalmente quando há resposta nela, o AP não é mais dono dela. Ele pode sugerir fechar dentro de um dos critérios existentes, mas não pode fechá-la ou removê-la mais. Se tem informação privada, pode pedir para tirar esta parte. Se não quer ser associado à pergunta, pode pedir para perder o vínculo, mas não pode definir o rumo do conteúdo. A comunidade pode fazer isto porque todo conteúdo aqui é comunitário. E a pergunta é boa em todos os sentidos. Não tem porque fechar.

Comment: Achei a pergunta ótima. Aliás, acho que ela esclarece de uma vez por todas que há uma distinção entre o ASP.NET, o ASP.NET MVC e o MVC apenas, este último sendo um padrão de design e não uma implementação.

Comment: @pnet Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 11):

**Não é correto**. É correto usar **ASP.NET MVC** ([veja o contexto na pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/96219/revisions)).

Isto é o nome de uma tecnologia da Microsoft. É um nome próprio e deve ser escrito da maneira correta. O nome é uma coisa só. Aí é correto usar para se referenciar a esta tecnologia específica que é diferente de MVC, é diferente do ASP.NET clássico que usa WebForms e principalmente é diferente do ASP clássico que não usa o .NET.

O ASP (Active Server Pages) era uma tecnologia que a Microsoft criou para fazer páginas web usando uma variação do Visual Basic original.

Quando ela criou o .NET, este *framework* que suporta as linguagens C# e VB.NET, entre outras, ela também criou uma nova versão desta tecnologia e chamou ela de ASP.NET. É algo bem diferente do ASP original e pode usar as linguagens .NET.

Note que **ASP** se escreve em maiúsculo porque é uma sigla. e **.NET** (lê-se "dotnet") não porque não é uma sigla (ainda que a Microsoft também use .NET em diversos lugares, então esta forma também está correta). O nome vem de rede, porque na época a Microsoft queria batizar tudo de "alguma coisa" ponto rede, para indicar que tudo seria feito para rodar em rede. A grosso modo é isto. Até o Windows ia se chamar Windows.NET, mas desistiram da ideia e só alguma coisas tiveram este sufixo. É óbvio que o .NET seria a tecnologia principal do Windows. Mas perceberam que era exagero.

Depois a Microsoft percebeu que muita gente não gostava do ASP.NET e havia quem utiliza-se o padrão [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Então ela criou outro *framework* do zero, completamente diferente, usando este padrão de projeto e chamou ele de ASP.NET MVC. Por razões óbvias foi incluída a sigla no nome (em maiúsculo, claro).

Inicialmente ele dependia de algumas partes do ASP.NET que muitas vezes chamamos de clássico para garantir que é o antigo, embora quando não se usa o MVC no nome, é dele que estamos falando, ainda que algumas pessoas usem errado.

Não acredito em programadores que não conseguem usar o nome da tecnologia corretamente. Pode parecer bobo, mas programação é detalhe. Se o programador não consegue saber o nome da tecnologia que ele está usando ele não saberá usá-la corretamente. Até que ele mude a sua atitude. Não confio em que fala "delfi" em vez de "delfái", que é o correto. É nome próprio, tem que falar certo. Ou a pessoa não é curiosa e ignora algo óbvio e fácil demais, ou sabe e é teimosa e descuidada. Ambas são características intrínsecas pessoais que impedem ela evoluir como profissional.

Hoje o [ASP.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52158/101) (sim, mais uma confusão, mas o nome inicial da tecnologia era pior) que é um conjunto de tecnologias que evoluíram em relação ao ASP.NET MVC (foram completamente reescritos e não há total compatibilidade), não depende de nada do antigo. E isto é importante. A tecnologia está atingindo a maturidade.

Pode achar confuso. E de fato a Microsoft não é boa para dar nomes, ou mesmo versionar produtos. Ela tenta usar critérios que só ela entende ser bom e confunde as pessoas.

E piorou porque agora [o .NET Core passa se chamar só .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101), um nome que nunca foi usado oficialmente antes.

Então, claro, **é correto usar esse nome** quando está usando [esta tecnologia](http://www.asp.net/mvc), mas é errado chamá-la apenas de MVC porque existem outros MVC, é errado chamar só de ASP.NET, pior ainda chamar de ASP, porque é outra tecnologia.

ASP.NET se tornou uma tecnologia legada, ainda suportada, mas não mais receberá evoluções significativas (ASP.NET MVC antigo também). Ela não se encaixa bem no ambiente web atual. Todo o conjunto de tecnologias do ASP.NET Core funcionam melhor para as necessidades atuais. E devemos evitar até mesmo misturá-las daqui pra frente.

Quem quiser entender melhor a tecnologia, [todos os fontes estão disponíveis para fazer o que quiser no Github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore).

Atualmente chamamos de .NET apenas, não usamos mais o nome Core.

Comment: Então, "delfi" ou "delfai" a palavra é grega, então deveria ser chamada na pronúncia grega e não americanizada, os americanos é que estão errados. http://dicionario.sensagent.com/M%C3%A9todo%20Delphi/pt-pt/ a correta pronúncia é "delfi" e não "delfai". Nós temos o hábito de nos deixar subjugar por culturas que se auto denominam superiores, como é o caso dos americanos e muitos brasileiros acham que tudo deles é correto e o nosso não.

Comment: O produto é americano. O nome próprio do produto é pronunciado assim. Tudo tem contexto. O produto da Embarcadero se pronuncia "delfai".

Comment: Eu ouvi muitas discussões desta nos EUA e lá colegas, não todos, mas alguns falavam delfi e não delfai, falo isso no próprio EUA, mas como queiram, só levantei essa questão porque você disse não confiar em quem fala delfi e não vejo nenhum mal nisso. O produto é americano, mas o nome não. Delphi vem do oráculo Delphus, como está no link passado.

Comment: Eu estou falando do produto, do nome próprio. Os cursos e palestras da Embarcadero (antes Borland, Inprise e outros nomes da empresa) falam assim. Indiretamente quase fiz um professor teimoso do Mackenzie ser demitido por causa deste assunto :) Depois dele ter colocado a corda no pescoço por conta própria, se salvou se retratando com outra professora que dominava o assunto de fato (linguística) e confirmou que era "delfai".

Comment: Então cara, você está se contradizendo nas suas palavras. Você disse que o nome deve ser falado de forma correta. O fato do produto ser americano, o nome não é e os gregos gostariam que o nome do oráculo deles fosse pronunciado de forma correta. Eu sou a favor da regionalização de nomes, como os americanos fazem e por isso eles pronunciam delfai, uma forma americanizada do nome delphi, que o correto é delfi(pronúncia). Mas todos temos nossa opinião e vou respeitar a sua, mas lembre-se, isso aqui é apenas uma discussão de opiniões, apenas, antes que outros venha e fale outra coisa. Big, valeu.

Comment: Você não está entendendo, você é quem começou falar de outra coisa. Eu estou falando do produto. O nome do produto se pronuncia "delfai". Se você acha que eles estão errados em nomear assim, você vai brigar com a empresa. Mas já adianto que o produto é deles, e eles chamam do que quiserem. Nome próprio deve ser usado da forma como ele foi definido por quem definiu. Não é uma questão de opinião. Claro que todo mundo tem o direito de falar como quiser, mas estará sempre fazendo por ignorância ou teimosia, não por estar seguindo alguma regra estabelecida.

Comment: bigown, não sou usuário das tecnologias, mas no próprio [site da Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/web-app-development-msdn#aspnet) aparece escrito .NET. Não seria um erro chamar de .Net então? Houve alguma mudança no padrão nos últimos anos?

Comment: @Molx não, de fato eles usam de um jeito ou de outro em lugares diferentes. Escrever .NET está correto como nome do produto. Como também usam minúsculo e não é uma sigla, eu não gosto de usar. De fato eles tentam padronizar o uso do .NET. Mas já vi eles usando outras variações inclusive. Eu nunca achei algo que dissesse claramente qual é o certo, então uso a lógica de que palavras que não são siglas não são escritas em maiúsculo.

Answer (score 9):

**MVC** é um padrão de arquitetura de software (**design pattern**) que separa a representação da informação da interação do usuário com ele.

**ASP.NET MVC** é uma estrutura de apresentação leve e altamente testável que (à semelhança dos aplicativos baseados em Web Forms) é integrada aos recursos **ASP.NET** existentes, como masters pages e autenticação baseada em associação. A estrutura MVC é definida no assembly `System.Web.Mvc`.

### Recursos da estrutura ASP.NET MVC

- Separação de tarefas do aplicativo (lógica de entrada, lógica de negócio e lógica da IU), possibilidade de testes e desenvolvimento controlado por testes (TDD). Todos os contratos núcleo na estrutura MVC são baseados na interface e podem ser testados usando objetos fictícios, que são objetos simulados que imitam o comportamento dos objetos reais no aplicativo. Você pode testar a unidade do aplicativo sem ter que executar os controladores em um processo ASP.NET, o que acelera e flexibiliza o teste da unidade. Você pode usar qualquer estrutura de teste da unidade que seja compatível com o .NET Framework.
- Uma estrutura extensível e conectável. Os componentes da estrutura ASP.NET MVC são desenvolvidos para serem facilmente substituídos ou personalizados. É possível conectar o seu próprio mecanismo de exibição, política de roteamento de URL, serialização de parâmetro ação-método e outros componentes. A estrutura ASP.NET MVC também suporta o uso dos modelos de contêiner de DI (Dependency Injection – Injeção de Dependência) e IOC (Inversion of Control – Inversão de Controle). A DI permite injetar objetos em uma classe, em vez de depender da classe para criar o objeto. A IOC especifica que se um objeto requer outro objeto, os primeiros objetos devem obter o segundo objeto de uma fonte exterior como um arquivo de configuração. Isto facilita os testes.
- Suporte abrangente para roteamento ASP.NET, que é um poderoso componente de mapeamento de URL que permite desenvolver aplicativos que têm URLs abrangentes e pesquisáveis. As URLs não precisam incluir extensões de nome de arquivo e são desenvolvidas para suportar padrões de denominação de URLs que funcionam bem para SEO (Search Engine Optimization – Otimização do Mecanismo de Pesquisa) e endereçamento REST (Representational State Transfer – Transferência de Estado Representacional).
- Suporte ao uso de marcação em arquivos de marcação de páginas ASP.NET (arquivos .aspx), de controle de usuário (arquivos .ascx) e de página mestra (arquivos .master) existentes como modelos de exibição. Você pode usar recursos ASP.NET existentes com a estrutura ASP.NET MVC, como páginas mestras aninhadas, expressões em linha (<%= %>), controles de servidor declarativos, modelos, vinculação de dados, localização e assim por diante.
- Suporte para recursos ASP.NET existentes. A estrutura ASP.NET MVC permite a utilização de recursos como autenticação de formulários e autenticação do Windows, autorização de URLs, associação e funções, caching de saída e dados, gerenciamento de estado de sessão e perfil, monitoramento de integridade, sistema de configuração e arquitetura de provedor.

É correto usar o termo se você está utilizando essa estrutura da Microsoft, caso contrário (estiver implementando o padrão em outra linguagem) você pode se referir apenas como **MVC**.

**Referência:** [Visão geral do ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx)