# Asp.Net MVC 5 vs Asp.Net MVC Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Vejo muitos falando do Asp.net Core. Será que vale a pena migrar MVC5 para Core ? Ou devo continuar com MVC5?

Comment: O Core é uma versão nova... O normal é a gente ir evoluindo as versões, certo?

Comment: Quer dizer que Core é a continuação do MVC5 ?

Comment: Grosso modo sim.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156517/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/225927/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49090/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111209/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96219/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183226/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52158/101.

Comment: Obrigado @bigown. Vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: O ASP.NET Core não é exatamente uma evolução do ASP.NET MVC 5, ele é outro produto com maneiras diferentes de fazer a maioria das coisas, embora algumas sejam iguais ou parecidas. Obviamente com muitas vantagens e quase nenhuma desvantagem. Se deve mudar ou não, depende de avaliação de muita coisa. Eu não faria projetos novos em tecnologia antiga, e se for fácil migraria para a nova.