# Instalar ASP.NET 5 em Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, asp.net-core

Li algumas notícias de que é possível instalar ASP.NET 5, em Linux. Alguém teria, por favor, algum tutorial legal que pudesse me auxiliar nisso? Gostaria de instalar no Ubuntu.

Comment: È só olhar na documentação oficial: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu Veja isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52158/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101

Comment: Com isso eu instalo .NET Core, não o ASP.NET 5.

Comment: E é com ele que instala o ASP.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para instalar o ASP.NET no Linux, siga as instruções a seguir, baseadas no seguinte link: https://talkitbr.com/2016/05/10/instalando-asp-net-5-no-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Instale os pré-requisitos, caso eles ainda não estejam na sua máquina:

```
sudo apt-get install unzip curl git
```

Atualize as referências do apt-get

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Instale o gerenciador de versões do .NET

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.sh | DNX_BRANCH=dev sh && source ~/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh
```

Instale o ambiente de execução .NET

```
sudo apt-get install libunwind8 gettext libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev zlib1g libicu-dev uuid-dev
dnvm upgrade -r coreclr
```

Instale o libuv

```
sudo apt-get install make automake libtool curl
curl -sSL https://github.com/libuv/libuv/archive/v1.8.0.tar.gz | sudo tar zxfv - -C /usr/local/src
cd /usr/local/src/libuv-1.8.0
sudo sh autogen.sh
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/src/libuv-1.8.0 && cd ~/
sudo ldconfig
```

Pronto, agora você pode baixar exemplos e executar aplicações .NET na usa máquina Ubuntu. Seguindo o tutorial indicado acima, veja os passos a seguir para rodar um exemplo de aplicação .NET

Crie um diretório de exemplos para aplicações ASP.NET

```
cd ~/ && mkdir aspnet-samples && cd ~/aspnet-samples
```

Clone o projeto ASP.NET 5

```
git clone https://github.com/aspnet/Home.git
```

Verifique a versão instalada na sua máquina para executar o sample correto:

```
dnx --version
```

Veja a versão utilizada. Quando executei tal comando, a versão retornada era a: .0.0-rc1-update1

Vá ao diretório referente a versão retornada pelo comando abaixo:

```
cd ~/aspnet-samples/Home/samples/1.0.0-rc1-update1/
```

Recupere os pacotes do NuGet

```
dnu restore
```

Vá ao diretório do sample HelloWeb

```
cd ~/aspnet-samples/Home/samples/1.0.0-rc1-update1/HelloWeb
```

Execute novamente o comando para recuperar as dependências do NuGet

```
dnu restore
```

E finalmente rode a aplicação

```
dnu web
```

No seu navegador, acesse a URL local http://localhost:5004 e veja a aplicação em execução.

Comment: Isto não funciona mais assim.

Comment: Acabei de executar os passos e funcionou

Comment: Sério isso @bigown?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/16/announcing-asp-net-core-rc2/

Comment: RC1 é feito dessa maneira

Comment: O post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/16/announcing-asp-net-core-rc2/ com certeza é válido, contudo não dá instruções mais específicas de como fazer isso.

Comment: Já não existe mais o aspnet 5, agora é o asp net core e saiu ontem o rc2