# É possível rodar ASP.NET MVC sem IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

É possível rodar uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC sem IIS?

Queria que o usuário pudesse rodar essa aplicação ASP.NET MVC sem precisar configurar o IIS, achei [este link](http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/host-your-own-web-server-in-your-application-using-iis-7-0-hostable-web-core//), mas não entendi como poderia aplicar em ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Isso é algo bem complicado de fazer. Já procurei por isso, o que achei foi através do  .Net Core (MVC5) que dá pra fazer com Kestrel ou WebListener.  O máximo que consegui com MVC4 foi rodar com IIS express, sendo esse inicializado por uma windows forms.

Comment: Murilo, teria como postar em exemplo com MVC4 e IIS Express?

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui https://gist.github.com/cairey/5501024 Talvez aparece alguém mais experiente pra te ajudar. Boa sorte ai

Comment: Em qual versão de ASP.NET MVC você quer isto?

Comment: Cigano, na versão 4.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

> É possível rodar uma aplicação asp.net mvc sem IIS?

Em resumo, não. O ASP.NET MVC4 é muito dependente do IIS.

> Queria que o usuário pudesse rodar essa aplicação asp.net mvc sem precisar configurar o IIS, achei [este link](http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/host-your-own-web-server-in-your-application-using-iis-7-0-hostable-web-core), mas não entendi como poderia aplicar em ASP.NET MVC.

Note que o Hostable WebCore (HWC) não deixa de ser uma extensão do IIS, só que de forma a permitir que sua própria aplicação seja também parte de uma implementação indireta do IIS.

[O código exemplo está inteiro aqui](http://www.carlosag.net/downloads/HWCServer.zip).

O grande problema desta abordagem é que ela é muito antiga. Este tipo de abordagem só existe para o IIS7, e exige que você monte uma aplicação console em separado apenas para executar um servidor que implementa uma boa parte do IIS7.

Answer (score 2):

## Sim, é possível

Pode não ser o que deseja, mas é possível.

Você precisa do [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) onde tem o novo ASP.NET MVC que não precisa de um servidor externo. E agora se tornou o padrão.

Mais informações em [O que é o ASP.NET vNext? Qual é o nome correto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52158/101).

Estude-o e entenda que é um produto diferente. Claro que terá que adaptar sua aplicação. Só você pode dizer se compensa ou não.

Também é possível rodar o [ASP.NET MVC tradicional com o Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/). Tem uma [análise mais profunda no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9768386/221800).

Fora isto não é possível, o ASP.NET original não foi desenvolvido para rodar sem um servidor HTTP integrado, mas não precisa ser o IIS.

Mais recentemente tem até um Proxy reverso próprio chamado [YARP](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: Eu não entendi os downvotes, e essa pergunta deveria ser marcada como a certa. +1 por ter citado o Mono também.

Comment: @Renan Eu entendi, eu falei em ASP.NET Core e tem gente que não gosta dele, acha que ninguém deveria usar e prefere ignorá-lo. Aí quem fala nele parece merecer negativo. Tem até um outro motivo menos óbvio que eu prefiro nem falar publicamente.

Comment: Complementando: [Hospedar o ASP.NET Core em um serviço Windows sem usar o IIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio), [Hospedar o ASP.NET Core no Linux com o Apache](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0), [Hospedar ASP.NET Core no Linux com Nginx](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-6.0) e [ASP.NET Core no Docker](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)